# tkinter simpledialog giving focus to parent of window it was called from when submitted

Tags: python, class, tkinter, dialog, simpledialog

I am attempting to open window2 from window1 and asking for a string in between.
On a successful (or unsuccessful) input, window1, seems to take focus back from window2. Even if focus_set is called on window2 after the dialogue is closed.

window2 takes focus on creation if he askstring is omitted

```py
import os
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import simpledialog

class window2:
    def __init__(self,root):
        self.root = root
        self.root.withdraw()
        simpledialog.askstring("askstring","askstring")
        self.root.deiconify()

class window1:
    def __init__(self,root):
        self.root = root
        self.button = tk.Button(self.root,text = "Test", command = self.newwindow)
        self.button.grid()
    
    def newwindow(self):
        newin = window2(tk.Toplevel(self.root))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    toproot = tk.Tk()
    win = window1(toproot)
    win.root.mainloop()
```

I'm wondering if it is doing this because of the way I've setup the classes or simply if its something simpledialogue does which triggers this effect.

Comment: This works perfectly for me: window1 opens, I click the "Test" button, window2 opens and asks for a string, and when the dialog closes, window2 has focus. Is this not what it was supposed to do?

Comment: Try adding `parent=self.root` to `askstring(...)`.

Comment: @acw1668 that and then OP can remove this line: `self.root.focus_set()`

Comment: @acw1668 That did work for this case, but I forgot to add in the `withdraw()` and `deiconify()` that I was using in my unsimplified case. Now this makes a little more sense as to why this occurs. Still not sure how to solve this other than to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

After noticing my simplified code was missing the `withdraw()` and the `deiconify()` I figured I could bring the window back to front once the window was visible again.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import simpledialog

class window2:
    def __init__(self,root:tk.Tk):
        self.root = root
        self.root.withdraw()
        simpledialog.askstring("this","sucks",parent = self.root)
        self.root.deiconify()
        self.root.wait_visibility()
        self.root.lift()
class window1:
    def __init__(self,root):
        self.root = root
        self.button = tk.Button(self.root,text = "Test", command = self.newwindow)
        self.button.grid()
    
    def newwindow(self):
        newin = window2(tk.Toplevel(self.root))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    toproot = tk.Tk()
    win = window1(toproot)
    win.root.mainloop()
```

Not exactly elegant, but it works.